# Moving Marker in a Google Map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create something similar to http://dev.syskall.com/map/

in my android phone application. Basically I have a List of GeoPoints and I need to make the car/marker move on the map according to the values of the geopoints. Putting the mapView code in a loop does not help at all! The map is invalidated till it reaches the last location in the list and then shows up with the latest location only so I cant see any movement of the marker.

If anyone has created this on android - please do get back to me! Appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0):

For such scenarios you cant use for loop or any other loop since it gets executed with in seconds and the points will move in seconds so cant observe the movement. in order to observe the movement in your case use use a timer that fires say every 200 millisecond. so that you can observe the movement in the map. As you decrease the time say 100 milliseconds you can observe it more clearly.